# Android: How to show video files in oval view

Tags: android, video, canvas, android-videoview

people. How to create my own CustomVideoView

I want show video files in my videoView in oval. But I don't know how to do it?
What myst I create: 
view or something else draw in canvas?
Please help me.
It's must look like this:
[image: It's must look like this]

I think that I can draw some Arc, but I don't know how make like i need.

Comment: Hi DavyJonesUA, How you are implemented circle VideoView? Would you please explain me how to do that.

Comment: Hi  Murali Ganesan, best solution was "putting a "mask" layer on top of a normal (square) VideoView" http://stackoverflow.com/a/14777143/895366

Comment: Hi DavyJonesUA, yeah i put mask but video not fill inside the mask top and bottom have space

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd have better luck just putting a "mask" layer on top of a normal (square) VideoView, rather than trying to create a new VideoView that draws on a circular canvas instead of a square one.

Here is some sudo code for a layout xml that I think would get you what you are looking for:

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <VideoView .../>
  <ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/mask"
    .../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Where the drawable "mask" is something that represents the black corner parts in your sample image, you could use a png, or even a shape drawable xml file if you want to work out the arcs to have it draw properly.

The ImageView should get drawn over top of the VideoView. Which will put the black corners in the proper place and leave the center circle transparent so that the VideoView below can be seen through it like a window sort of.

Comment: Thx... I make it with png. But what about different screen size on different mobiles? How to fix it? because png is in px and my VideoView in dip..

Comment: Need I create 4 png files for xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, ldpi ?

Comment: @DavyJonesUA that is one solution yes. Another option if you don't care about it being ovular instead of perfectly circular you could still use a single png but make it a 9patch that is allowed to stretch in the very middle.